# patch 7405 error in magento 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405

I installed 7405 patch but its getting error

```
            sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.1.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-41-06.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 505.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
```

patch not applied

Comment: I think patch already applied , please check patch at here http://magereport.com/

Comment: Have You made any changes into Magento Core files?

Comment: no its not applied , its not showed in applied.patch.list @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: i replaced fresh magento1.9.1.1 core files still not applied @KonradSiamro

Comment: Have You installed previous SUPEE?

Comment: yes @KonradSiamro

Comment: The patch chain you need to make sure has been applied is as follows in the list order: SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7405.

Comment: I installed orderly only @KonradSiamro

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Unable-to-install-SUPEE-7405-1-1-2-23-2016/td-p/30225 try last post

Comment: checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 264.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED